# How to stop rabbitmq server on windows 7

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, amqp

I have installed RabbitMQ server on my windows 7 machine.
I am not able to stop the service by running this command in rabbitmq command line `rabbitmq-server.bat -detached` and `rabbitmq-service.bat stop`

I am getting the following errors in console :

`C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.5.4\sbin>rabbitmq-serve
r.bat -detached
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "MYPC"`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.5.4\sbin>rabbitmq- servi
ce.bat stop
 C:\Program Files\erl7.0\erts-7.0\bin\erlsrv: Failed to stop service RabbitMQ.
Error: The operation completed successfully.`

Comment: Try running the commands with the same user that started the broker in the first place, perhaps as administrator. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/windows-quirks.html

Comment: have you try running CMD as administrator, then run "rabbitmq-service.bat stop" ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to stop and to restart the Windows services.
[image: Services]

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands

```
rabbitmq-service.bat stop  
rabbitmq-service.bat install  
rabbitmq-service.bat start
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, this is work... just use first line for stop server rabbitMQ...

Answer (score 0):

**For windows**

Open Rabbitmq cmd shell and type the following

```
rabbitmq-plugins disable rabbitmq_management
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers appear to all be for when RabbitMQ is installed as a service.

If one is running RabbitMQ via `rabbitmq-server.bat -detached`, the command for shutting it down is `rabbitmqctl.bat shutdown`